# A main clause that doesn't follow from a subordinate clause

Tags: clauses, subordinate-clauses

> Because it's raining outside, I'm wearing orange socks today.

What is the term for this kind of sentence?  Closest I can find is *non sequitur*?

Furthermore, do the below concepts have names?

1. A subordinate clause whose corresponding main clause doesn't follow from it
2. A main clause which doesn't follow from its corresponding subordinate clause
3. A pair of clauses, one subordinate and one main, in which the main doesn't follow from the subordinate

Comment: There are no terms for them because "subordinate clause" and "main clause" are grammatical terms and not semantic or rhetorical ones. Therefore, since English grammar has no concept of "following from", whatever is meant by that phrase, it has no terms for it.

Comment: Yes, I would call it a _non sequitur_.

Comment: Yes, or semantically inappropriate. Note, though, that the _because_ expression is not a subordinate clause. It's a preposition phase headed by the preposition "because".

Comment: I'd just call it nonsense.